# is there a way assign IF statement or Switch Case to a variable

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I am trying assign grades for input integers. But I found it difficult to complete the code. Is there any other way to do the below code such that it will give me desired result?

=========================

```
$grade = {if($ave>=90 && $ave<100) {
    echo "A";
}
else if ($ave>=60 && $ave<90) {
    echo "B";
}
else {
    echo "F9";
}
return 0;
}
```

================================

```
<td><?php echo $fetch['name']?></td>
<td><?php echo $fetch['eng']?></td>
<td><?php echo $fetch['mat']?></td>
<td><?php echo $fetch['lit']?></td>
<td><?php echo $grade ?></td>
```

The grade will be assigned based on the Average i.e ($ave). I have done the average but the grade is the issue.

Comment: Why is an average of 100 not considered an "A" ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case for using [`match`](https://www.php.net/match), introduced with PHP 8. To evaluate statements (as true or not) and assign values accordingly, we can use `match(true)` as follows:

```
$grade = match(true) {
    $ave>=90 && $ave<100 => 'A',
    $ave>=60 && $ave<90 => 'B'
    default => 'F9'
};
```

If you are yet to upgrade to PHP 8, you can use the [`switch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) in its place, which is more verbose, but still cleaner and easier to update than a series of `if/elseif/else` statements:

```
switch(true) {
    case $ave>=90 && $ave<100:
        $grade = 'A';
        break;
    case $ave>=60 && $ave<90:
        $grade = 'B';
        break;
    default:
        $grade = 'F9';
        break;
}
```

Assuming you'll reuse this logic e.g. for grades on different subjects, wrap it in a function:

```
function get_grade(int $ave): string {
    return match(true) {
        $ave>=90 && $ave<100 => 'A',
        $ave>=60 && $ave<90 => 'B'
        default => 'F9'
    };
}
```

If you need to use `switch`, it becomes a bit less verbose inside a function, since you can swap "assign and `break`" with an immediate `return`:

```
function get_grade(int $ave): string {
    switch(true) {
        case $ave>=90 && $ave<100:
            return 'A';
        case $ave>=60 && $ave<90:
            return 'B';
        default: 
            return 'F9';
    }
}
```

If your averages may also be floats (*90.5* etc.), change the function argument signature to a union type declaration `int|float` instead (also available as of PHP 8).

Comment: @IpayeOlumideDavid in that case, I've updated the answer to include "`switch` in `function`", we can make it a bit less verbose by immediate return where a case matches. Really you could also drop the `default` case and just end your function with `return 'F9';`, however I've kept it inside the switch to keep alike things grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

That might help...

```php
function grade(int $ave)
{
    if ($ave >= 90 && $ave < 100) {
        return 'A';
    }

    if ($ave >= 60 && $ave < 90) {
        return 'B';
    }

    return 'F9';
}

<td><?php echo grade($ave); ?></td>
```

Comment: I still get error.
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare grade() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\index.php:63) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sampleindex.php on line 63. and here is line 63 function grade(int $ave)

Comment: Make sure you have the function `grade` only once in your code.

Comment: Also recommend using more descriptive function names, since a function simply called `grade` could be for `get_grade`, `set_grade`, `calculate_grade`, `change_grade`, `publish_grade`, or whatever else ie. it's not immediately obvious what it's for. Really `get_grade_from_average` or `average_to_grade` would be "properly descriptive names".